# How can I get HAML syntax styling to work in Sublime Text?

Tags: haml, sublimetext3

I tried following the instructions but I've had no luck getting HAML to show up as an option in the Syntax list. I've got package control installed, I just don't know how to get the HAML in there.

I'm using Sublime Text 3.

Currently, I'm just using the Ruby Syntax instead which seems to be ok but the documents never remember that I picked that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the [`Haml`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Haml) package with Package Control. Open the Command Palette (**`Tools -> Command Palette`**) and type in ***`pci`*** to bring up the `Package Control: Install Package` option. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and wait for the package list to load. Once loaded, type ***`haml`*** and select the first entry - it should say `HAML Bundle for Textmate`. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and watch the status bar at the bottom of the window until it prints a message about successfully installing the package. You can now select `Ruby HAML` from the list of syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked! Also, I had been looking all along for "HAML" instead of "Ruby HAML" but I think now any .haml file will get the right highlighting as soon as I open it. So much nicer!!!